# sam local invoke from pure stdin

Tags: amazon-web-services, git-bash, aws-sam-cli

with --help i can see

> Invoking a Lambda function using input from stdin
>
> `$ echo '{"message": "Hey, are you there?" }' | sam local invoke "HelloWorldFunction" --event -`

And it works as such. But trying to make use of stdin without piping an echo:

```
sam local invoke "HelloWorldFunction" --event -
```

it just lets me write without end.
I've tried <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> but it just prints ^D

And of course <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> aborts the command without executing.

How can I use pure stdin for it? How can i signal the end of input?

note: i'm using git bash for windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ENTER</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (again) will send an EOF in Windows.